# Facebook login 500 error

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, blackberry

I am using old facebook api v1.0 to login to facebook in blackberry app. Following is the url I am requesting

**https://m.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=451146618261729&v=1.0&next=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&_rdr**

I am receiving **HTTP 500** error if I even hit this url in browser. It was working fine when I use older application id but it had another issue of returning error code **104**, incorrect signature so I tried creating new app id and it is now giving 500 internal error.

If relevant my target blackberry OS is 6.0

Comment: same problem to me 104 error. from last 3 days...........

Comment: I hope someone knows the workaround.

Comment: its not showing the loging page also

Comment: just clean your simulator and try again. it will works.

Comment: I m trying it on device. How to clean the device? I tried removing the app but still same.